# $.ajax not bringing my json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

the retorno json_encode it's not returning anything

this is the js controller i would like to return the json "retorno"

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'controll/busqueda.php',
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        "precio_min": "",
        "precio_max": "",
        "rate": "",
        "asignatura": ""
    },
    success: function(retorno) {
        alert(retorno.profesores);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("aaaaa");
    },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

this is the php file where i call the model db and $retorno is a stdClass() from the data base where i put in it profesores

```
if($precio_max != "" || $precio_min != ""){
   $retorno = $busqueda->profesor_precio($precio_min,$precio_max);
}else{
    if($rate != ""){
        $retorno = $busqueda->profesor_rate($rate);
    }else{
        if($asignatura != ""){
            $retorno = $busqueda->profesor_asig($asignatura);
        }else{
            $retorno = $busqueda->profesor();
        }
    }
}

 echo json_encode($retorno, true);
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: oh and the result from retorno.profesores is always undefined and it should be and array

Comment: So - it's not your AJAX, it's your PHP that doesn't work.

Comment: well when i test it calling it from localhost/... it print everything how it should have been

Answer (score 2):

1) your server must return correct response with header: `Content-type: application/json`. You can do it in php with that code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

you have to send this header before any of your `echo`.

2) set `dataType` property for ajax request. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'controll/busqueda.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        param: 'value'
    },
    success: function(retorno) {
        alert(retorno.profesores);
    },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

3) make sure that your request to `controll/busqueda.php` returns valid json data. Check your response from `http://yourhost.name/controll/busqueda.php` Is it returns valid json?

Comment: i did all that and is not working it actually giving only error now

Comment: this should be my json when i try it on localhost/.../busqueda.php 
{"respuesta":200,"info":"Profesores Encontrados","profesores":[{"id_profesor":"1","nombre":"Guillermo","email":"memonte@gmail.com","contra":"memo20","nacimiento":"1994-10-11","sexo":"0","telefono":"424223344","precio":"2000","foto":null}]

Comment: you miss `}` at the end of response. Is that just a typo?

Comment: try `url: '/controll/busqueda.php'` instead of `url: 'controll/busqueda.php'`

Comment: what is the addres of your html page where your JavaScript code is executed? it it at the same domain as your request to `busqueda.php` script? Show, please, full URLs of yours html and json requests.

Comment: no this is a .js document not an html and everything is on a diferent folder the js is on js folder and de busqueda.php is on a controll folder and all this folders are on a www folder the html folders are on a view folder i just call the js i'm using ionic framework right now

Comment: i just found something to see the error from the ajax and it says SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Unexpected token means: 1) some error in your javascript code at the page  or 2) json in your server response is not valid. Check console(F12) network tab try to find the line with response from your server and check headers and body of response.